# How can I centrally set a `content-type` in Karate without it being overwritten to 'application/json' when there's a request body?

Tags: karate

I have a  `* configure headers = read('classpath:configure-headers.js')` in the Background of each of my feature files.

The `configure-header.js` looks like:

```
function() {
    var out = {'Some-Header-We-Need': 'value'};
    var authToken = karate.get('authToken');
    if(authToken) {
        out['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authToken;
        out['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.mycompany+json';
    }
    return out;
}
```

These headers always appear where I expect, except that when I'm making a `PUT` or `PATCH` or `POST`, the Content-Type header is being set to `application/json`. I can get my desired header by setting it before the call, e.g.

```
Given path myPath
And header Content-Type = 'application/vnd.mycompany+json'
And request read('classpath:requestBody.json')
When method POST
```

What can I do to not need to rewrite this header everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, you actually did surface a bug in Karate that went un-detected for a long time. Thanks !

I've opened an issue here, and the fix is in the develop branch: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/510

Hopefully you can manage for a little while with the work-around. If urgent we can release a patch version.